# 5V voltage regulator output voltage

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I am using a MC78M05 voltage regulator to supply a microcontroller with 5V from a 7.5V input voltage. When I want to programm the card, the system is not working and there is no 5V supplied by the MC78M05 (the system is off, input regulator=0V). The 5V is supplied by the external programming signals like this:

[image]

My question is:

Can we destroy the 5V regulator by supplying the output to 5V with no input voltage in the voltage regulator?

Research:

I looked to the inside of the voltage regulator:

[image]

I note that we have a voltage to the emitter transistors bipolar. I don't know the risk of supplying the output voltage regulator when the input is 0V.

Comment: Just a side note - when the µC is supposed to be off, ensure no voltage is going to any µC pin, even through a high resistance.  The internal protection diodes will conduct and  the chip [can be powered on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yFh7Vv0Paw) from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, forcing reverse current through a linear regulator like this can destroy it. The 78xx series is not designed specifically to survive this.

You should protect the regulator with a diode from its output back to its input, as shown below. This means that the programmer will also have to supply some voltage to the circuitry before the regulator (if there is any).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Gl5Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How do you know if a linear regulator is protected or not against this kind of operation ?

Comment: The datasheet will spell this out as a feature, most likely right on the first page. If it doesn't say anything about it, it's unprotected.